# Auto-filtering Excel Range based on input range

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

In an excel spreadsheet I have 3 columns of data. Column A+B have text inputted and  column C is numerical (1-5). I will be creating an input box. depending on the input it will filter the results for column C.

For example :

if I inputted G this conditions will filter the results for column C having 1,2 & 4

if i inputted A this conditions will filter the results for column C having 1 & 3

is this possible to do? my thought was these macros to filter the results and then export it to a new spreadsheet. Is there any other way of doing this ? Sorry for the award explanation :S

Comment: Are those the conditions?  If G then Show C with 1,2,4 and if A, then 1,3?  Are there other conditions?

Comment: G = (1 and 2 and 3) or (1 or 2 or 3)?

Comment: @MaciejLos That is correct G = (1 and 2 and 3)

Comment: @peege Thats correct they are the conditions if G is inputted on the input box, column D needs to be filtered showing only rows which have values of 1,2,4 then copied to a new workbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the `Range.AdvancedFilter` method [further described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to filter your data, based on user input, and copies the filtered data to a second worksheet in the same workbook.

Because AdvancedFilter requires some 'setting-up' the following assumptions have been made in my example.  You may need to change these for your requirements.

There are two worksheets, one (called Data) containing your data; and the second (called Results) containing the AdvancedFilter criteria and the copied results.  This second sheet is assumed to be a blank sheet.  The criteria are programmatically applied to this sheet.

Your Data must have data headings.  If you change the heading called 'Criteria' in my example then you will need to also change this in the code.

[image: Data]

You can add additional filter criteria within the code should you wish.

If no, or an unknown filter ID is entered into the inputbox, then all the data is copied to the Results sheet.  The results sheet is automatically cleared if the Sub is re-run.  An example of applying filter value G is shown below:

[image: Results for filter 'G']

```
Option Explicit
Sub advFiltVals()

Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
Dim frstRow As Long, lstRow As Long, stcol As Long, endcol As Long
Dim critStRow As Long, critStCol As Long
Dim copyStRow As Long, copyStCol As Long
Dim filtVal As String
Dim critRng As Range, copyToRng As Range

Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
Set wsResult = Sheets("Results")

'data
frstRow = 1
stcol = 1
endcol = 3
'result
critStRow = 1   'header row
critStCol = 1
copyStRow = 2
copyStCol = 3

    With wsResult
        .UsedRange.Clear
        Set copyToRng = .Cells(copyStRow, copyStCol)
        .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Value = "Criteria"

        filtVal = InputBox("Enter filter value.")

        Select Case UCase(filtVal)
            Case Is = "A"
                .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Offset(1, 0) = 1
                .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Offset(2, 0) = 3
                Set critRng = .Range(.Cells(critStRow, critStCol), .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Offset(2, 0))
            Case Is = "G"
                .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Offset(1, 0) = 1
                .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Offset(2, 0) = 2
                .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Offset(3, 0) = 4
                Set critRng = .Range(.Cells(critStRow, critStCol), .Cells(critStRow, critStCol).Offset(3, 0))
            Case Else
                Set critRng = .Cells(critStRow, critStCol)
        End Select
    End With

    With wsData
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If

        lstRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, endcol).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range(.Cells(frstRow, stcol), .Cells(lstRow, endcol))
            .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=critRng, CopyToRange:=copyToRng, Unique:=False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```